# Custom error with typescript, problem in types: has no properties in common with type

Tags: typescript

Hello I'm trying to make a custom error, I started making a base error, but I'm having problems with interfaces and types

this is my code:

```
export interface errors_fields {
  field: string;
  code: string;
}

export interface configError {
  type?: string;
  message?: string;
  code?: number;
  errors?: object[] | null | errors_fields | errors_fields[];
  internalData?: object;
  options?: {
    showPath?: boolean;
    showLocations?: boolean;
  };
}

export class BaseError extends ExtendableError {
  type: string;
  message: string;
  code: number;
  errors: object[] | null | errors_fields | errors_fields[];
  internalData: object;
  path: any;
  locations: any;
  _showLocations: boolean = false;
  _showPath: boolean = false;

  constructor(configError: configError) {
    super((configError && configError.message) || '');
    const type = configError.type;
    const message = configError.message;
    const code = configError.code;
    const errors = configError.errors;
    const internalData = configError.internalData;
    const options = configError.options;

    this.type = type;
    this.message = message;
    this.code = code;
    this.errors = errors;
    this.internalData = internalData;
    this._showLocations = !options.showLocations;
    this._showPath = !options.showPath;
  }

  serialize(): configError {
    const { type, message, code, errors, path, locations } = this;

    let error: configError = {
      type,
      message,
      code,
      errors,
    };

    return error;
  }
}

export const isInstance = (e) => e instanceof BaseError;

export class UnprocessableEntityERROR extends BaseError {
  constructor(errors: errors_fields[]) {
    super(errors);
    this.type = 'Unprocessable Entity';
    this.message = 'Validation Failed';
    this.code = 422;
    this.errors = errors;
  }
}
```

and throw error with this:

```
let validationErrors: InputErrors[] = [];
let user = await this.userRep.findOne({ where: { email: data.email } });
//email length
if (!(data.email.length > 1 && data.email.length < 250)) {
  validationErrors.push({ field: 'email', code: 'invalid_field' });
}
if (!(data.name.length > 1 && data.name.length < 250)) {
  validationErrors.push({ field: 'name', code: 'invalid_field' });
}

throw new UnprocessableEntityERROR(validationErrors);
```

but I am having problems with my UnprocessableEntity class constructor, basically I will only receive errors (fields with errors)

i got this error:

> Type 'errors_fields[]' has no properties in common with type
>   'configError'.ts(255)

on my UnprocessableEntityERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reduced code that reproduces the error:

```
export interface errors_fields {
  field: string;
}

export interface configError {
  type: string;
}

export class BaseError {
  constructor(configError: configError) {
  }
}

export class UnprocessableEntityERROR extends BaseError {
  constructor(errors: errors_fields[]) {
      super(errors); // Incompatible
  }
}
```

The reason why you are getting the error is that `errors_fields[]` cannot be passed to the `BaseError` constructor. You need to pass in a `configError`.

## Fix

Create a `configError` in your super call e.g.

```
export interface errors_fields {
  field: string;
}

export interface configError {
  type: string;
}

export class BaseError {
  constructor(configError: configError) {
  }
}

export class UnprocessableEntityERROR extends BaseError {
  constructor(errors: errors_fields[]) {
      super({type: 'something'}); // OKAY
  }
}
```